# Loop through database ANYLOGIC

Tags: anylogic

In my model I want to loop through the database which contains multiple columns (see example) by an event. The idea behind it is that I want to create dynamic events based on the rows in the database.

[image]

But I've no clue how to iterate through a database in anylogic and also was not able to find an example of a loop with a database.

The dummycode of my problem would look something like this:

```
For order in orderdatabase:
   Create order based on (order.name, order.quantity, order.arrivaltime, order.deliverylocation)
```

Where order in the loop is every row of the database, and the value on which the creation is based based on the different column values of that specific row.

Can somebody give me a simple example of how to create such a loop for this specific problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the database query wizard:

1. put your cursor into a code field
2. this will allow you to open the database wizard
   [image]
3. select what you need (in your case, you want the "iterate over returned rows  and do something" option
   [image]
4. Click ok
5. adjust the dummy code to make it do what you want

For details and examples, check the example models and the AnyLogic help, explaining all options in detail.